# Adding hyperlink to fancy slides presentation

Tags: errors, presentations

I will admit that I'm a newcomer to LaTeX, especially presentations. I'm trying to add a hyperlink to slide in my presentation and I keep getting the error: `Argument of \frame has an extra }`. I've tried a lot of different thing just from reading these threads and nothing seems to work. The code is below:

```
\documentclass{fancyslides}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % Allows the usage of non-english characters
\usepackage{times} % Use the Times font
\usepackage{booktabs} % Allows the use of \toprule, \midrule and \bottomrule in tables
\graphicspath{{images/}} % Location of the slide background and figure files

\usetheme{default} 
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{} % Disable the slide navigation buttons on the bottom of each slide
\setbeamercolor{structure}{fg=\yourowntexcol} % Define the color of titles and fixed text elements (e.g. bullet points)
\setbeamercolor{normal text}{fg=\yourowntexcol} % Define the color of text in the presentation

\newcommand{\structureopacity}{0.75} % Opacity (transparency) for the structure elements (boxes and circles)

\newcommand{\strcolor}{blue} % Set the color of structure elements (boxes and circles)
\newcommand{\yourowntexcol}{white} 

\newcommand{\titlephrase}{Introduction to American Government} % Presentation title
\newcommand{\name}{John D'Attoma} % Presenter's name
\newcommand{\affil}{University of Missouri} % Presenter's institution
\newcommand{\email}{johndattoma@umsl.edu} % Presenter's email address

\begin{document}

\startingslide %

\fbckg{3.jpg} % Slide background image
\begin{frame}{fragile}
\pointedsl \href{https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WINDtlPXmmE}{\LARGE American Politics}}
% Text in this environment is printed in a circle and will be made large and uppercase - if you need to fit more text in you can reduce the font size within the \pointedsl{} bracket as usual, e.g. \pointedsl{\large smaller main point}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Thanks!

Comment: You might want to mention that you're using a not-entirely standard package [`fancyslides`](http://www.staff.amu.edu.pl/~p_lup/?page_id=1057).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you aren't supplying the URL as an "argument" to `\pointedsl`.   Indeed, if you count the braces in your MWE, you'll see that there is no match for the rightmost `}` after "American Politics".

Substituting in the following line works for me:

```
\pointedsl{{\tiny \href{https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WINDtlPXmmE}{American Politics}}}
```